# Angular JS hide / show both per item and for all items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a repeater with a headline and a description for each item. I want to be able to hide all descriptions at once with the help of a checkbox. This was easily done. Then i want to be able to hide or show each of the descriptions separately too. And i have almost got it working, except for one problem: if i hide all descriptions with the checkbox, and then click on one description to show it nothing happens until i click it a second time.

Is there any way around it?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="container" ng-app="" ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="MinAllDescriptions" /> <span>Minimize all descriptions</span><br /><br />

    <div class="itemContainer" ng-repeat="item in ItemList">
        <span class="itemHeadline">{{item.Headline}}</span> 
        <a href="#" ng-click="MinThisDescription = !MinThisDescription">Hide / Show</a>
        <div class="itemDescription" ng-hide="MinAllDescriptions || MinThisDescription" ng-show="!MinAllDescriptions || !MinThisDescription">{{item.Description}}</div>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
function myController($scope) {
    $scope.MinAllDescriptions = false;
    $scope.ItemList = [
        {Headline: "Item one", Description: "This is item one"},
        {Headline: "Item two", Description: "This is item two"},
        {Headline: "Item three", Description: "This is item three"},
        {Headline: "Item four", Description: "This is item four"},
        {Headline: "Item five", Description: "This is item five"}
    ];
}
</script>
```

Check out jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/195k2e9n/1/

Comment: Why don't you bind MinThisDescription with item present in itemList ?

Comment: you have both ng-show & ng-hide on same tag, remove that and put one logic

Comment: Hey, Its like tristate checkbox implementation. You should show/hide based on MinThisDescription only. Also MinAllDescriptions click should set/reset all MinThisDescription based on whether there is at least one item visible. You can mimic the gmail behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/7Lbgjvz7/

Html

```
<div id="container" ng-app="" ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="minimizeAll()" ng-model="MinAllDescriptions" /> <span>Minimize all descriptions</span><br /><br />

    <div class="itemContainer" ng-repeat="item in ItemList">
        <span class="itemHeadline">{{item.Headline}}</span> 
        <a href="#" ng-click="item.MinThisDescription = !item.MinThisDescription">Hide / Show</a>
        <div class="itemDescription" ng-hide="item.MinThisDescription">{{item.Description}}</div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular

```
function myController($scope) {
    $scope.MinAllDescriptions = false;
    $scope.ItemList = [
        {Headline: "Item one", Description: "This is item one"},
        {Headline: "Item two", Description: "This is item two"},
        {Headline: "Item three", Description: "This is item three"},
        {Headline: "Item four", Description: "This is item four"},
        {Headline: "Item five", Description: "This is item five"}
    ];

    $scope.minimizeAll = function(){
        angular.forEach($scope.ItemList, function(item, i){
            item.MinThisDescription = !$scope.MinAllDescriptions;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event into checkbox and set $scope.MinAllDescriptions = !$scope.MinAllDescriptions